# Firebase crash reporting not getting displayed on Console - beginner

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have added Firebase Crash-Reporting to my project. I did everything as described in the documentation. I also get the following message printed on the console. But the error doesn't get displayed on Firebase console. WHy is this? and how can I solve this ?

```
Dec 20 01:10:47  App[14262] <Notice>: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40005000 started
Dec 20 01:10:47  App[14262] <Notice>: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http: // goo.gl/RfcP7r)
Dec 20 01:10:47  App[14262] <Notice>: [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
Dec 20 01:10:49  App[14262] <Notice>: [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA100002] Crashes uploaded successfully: (
        1e21a90b1c000000
    )
```

**UPDATE**

**Crashlytic**

Added the following in Pod

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
```

Added `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` as a new run script

Added `GoogleService-Info.plist` downloaded from Firebase console.

Then tried to crash the code using `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`

Comment: I wouldn't use firebase crash-reporting to be honest, check out crashlytics. https://try.crashlytics.com/

Comment: Please contact Firebase support if you're having trouble.  I don't think anyone on Stack Overflow will be able to help. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @TNguyen Already tried, but its the same problem. I don't see the records on the console. Why is this ? I have been trying this my entire day. :-/

Comment: how are you trying it? you can't use the simulator it has to be with a device i believe. Assuming you've set it up correctly, can you tell me the exact, step-by-step things you are doing?

Comment: I followed everybit that's given on this link. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0 . Check my updated post. I have added the steps I took. Just asking does it take 24 hours for Crashes to display on the console ?

Comment: don't follow that one, it's not as clear as this one here https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install. Follow that one, it's extremely easy to setup

Comment: @TNguyen I follwed that too. but then finally i have to migrate my app to Firebase as Fabric will be taken over by Firebase. So, I am again stuck with firebase not displaying the crash records.

Comment: did you find anything I am facing the same thing with crashlytics

Comment: @MoazKhan No, stuck with the same issue. Let ,me know if you find anything useful./

Comment: I tried every solution there is but still unable to make it work my upload is also successful. But when I go and double click CLI of pods/Fabric/uploadDSYM .. then it says unable to find GoogleServiceInfoPlist so DSYM will not be uploaded ....although it's there and included in my project target. I ready somewhere that if DSYM aren't upload then even with successful upload we won't see the crash on dashboard. So try to add GoogleServiceInfo plist in some other new way ... maybe it will work for you.

Comment: @MoazKhan Seems like there was an issue with Firebase, it works now.

Comment: What did you do ? It still doesn't work for me

Comment: Well, it all started to work after writing to firebase about the issue. firebase-support@google.com

Comment: @llep i am also facing the same issue can you tell me what you added for shell script.

Comment: @salmansiddiqui I think it was a bug, so I emailed firebase and it started to work the next morning. Send an email to ` firebase-support@google.com`

Comment: @llep sure Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Most of you have resolved the issue including me but I am writing the answer here which worked for me as well as for some other developers. Google crashlytics developers also thanked me for pointing out the issue on Github.

If you have done everything and it's still not working then add the crash

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

at the very start of the app, for example in the first view controller that opens up in your app. After like 5 minutes check crashlytics it will start working.